# In Class Library Project missing "System.ServiceModel"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have a Class Library project which is made in 3.5 framework. Now I want to update this project into framework 4.0. By using project property I have changed this project from 3.5 into 4.0 Target framework. Now it gives me an error i.e.

> Error : The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Before this when this project in 3.5 framework it builds successfully but after changing 4.0 framework it throws this error.

I made a new reference of System.ServiceModel of 4.0.0.0 version like this :
[image]

but after that adding this new System.ServiceModel dll it shows the same error like this :
[image]

How can I converted this 3.5 project into 4.0?

How can Resolve this error?

Comment: Probably DLL names in the config files will need to have v4.0 version numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps you have described seem correct. The yellow question mark should disappear after you compile.

1. Change the target .NET framework from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 (**not** .NET 4.0 Client Profile otherwise the System.ServiceModel assembly will not appear in the Add Reference dialog)
2. Add reference to `System.ServiceModel` 4.0.0.0 to the project